# how to validate sentence of minimum 3 words and no URL allowed using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I wanted to create a regex to validate a minimum of 3 words and no URL allowed:

Here's the regex I have so far for a minimum of 3 words:

```
"minimumThreeWordsAndNoURL": {
                    "regex": /^/\b\w{1,2}\b/$/,
                    "alertText": "Minimum of 3 words and no URL allowed"
                },
```

and here's the regex for the URL

```
 "url": {
                "regex": /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i,
                "alertText": "* Invalid URL"
            },
```

how do I combine this such that I want 3 words and no URL are allowed in the textarea?

Comment: Why does it need to be combined into one Regex? You must be calling these Regexes somewhere so why not check that one returns true and the other returns false. Would also make your code more readable rather than having one monster Regex that does everything.

Comment: Are you sure the 3 words works? It doesn't seem like it should even compile.

Comment: Your URL regex is missing some of the possible URL schemes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes

Comment: @Jerry yes it seems the 3 words doesn't work... can anyone help me out?

Comment: @adit Well, you could use something like this for the 3 words validation: `/^\S+(?: +\S+){0,2}$/` which accepts only three sets of characters separated by at least one space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaitanya raises a valid point: unless you're playing Regex Golf or solving a homework assignment, you don't need to cram all the functionality into a single regex.  Using a pair of regexes means your url-matcher will be easier to read, and your code in general will be easier to understand.

Something like the following (with an, admittedly, incomplete url matcher) will get you most of the way:

```
function validate(str) {
 var phrase = /^(\b\S+\b\s?){3,}$/,
   url = /^((http|https|ftp):\/\/)?\w+(\.\w+)+(\/\w+)*(\?(\w+=\w+)(&\w+=\w+)*)?$/;

 return phrase.test(str) && !url.test(str);
}
```

Comment: @Nate the issue with this is that this doesn't allow special characters in the words, which I want to allow special characters. So how to revise it?

Comment: @adit: see edit.  I updated 'phrase' to use \S (any non-whitespace) instead of \w (any word character).  That should be very permissive.